# В каком случае следует применять конструктор

Tags: php, конструктор

Добрый день.

Вопрос очень сильно мучает меня: обязательно ли использовать конструкторы в классах? Да, если пишем что-то фундаментальное вроде ORM, то без них никуда. Для меня наличие конструкторов весьма удобная вещь, но отсутствие механизмов перезагрузки огорчает. И тут либо  костыли с параметрами, либо патерн фабрики, либо наследование. Насколько критична передача параметров прямо в метод? Да, это некрасиво и другой программист это не сможет использовать (но если проект личный).

```
class Client extends database {

private $salt = '+^HDF*FGKCM';

public function  LoadClient($login,$password) {

    $DBH = Registry::get('DBH');

    $STH = $DBH ->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `login` = :login and `password` = :password" );

    $STH->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $STH->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $STH->execute();

    $result = $STH->fetchAll();

    return $result;
 }
public function CheckMark($id,$status)  {
..........
..........
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> и другой программист это не сможет использовать

Другим программистом можете оказаться Вы. Через пару дней.

Если Ваш метод "чистый", то есть не изменяет внутренностей объекта, внешних переменных (но такое бывает) и зависит только от своих аргументов, то это хороший кандидат на статический метод. И хорошая практика.

Comment: А если этот метод не изменяет внутренностей объекта, но создает и записывает переменные сессии. Тогда как быть?

Comment: Это также хороший кандидат на статический метод.